# C++ narrowing error

Tags: c++

I am a newbie to C++ and got stuck with this.

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    bool a = 2;
    bool e { 4 }; //error
    std::cout << a << e;
    std::cin.get();

}
```

I get error as `'initializing': truncation from 'int' to 'bool'`. Why does `a` work and not `e`?

Comment: More to the point, why are you initialising a boolean with an integer?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Trying to set `4` to a boolean variable?

Comment: Trying to initialize `bool` to nonzero (`True`)

Comment: ***Why does a work and not e?*** Because {} checks for narrowing when = does not. With that said it's unclear why you are doing this conversion from an int to a bool in the first place?

Comment: There's probably a warning for the first one as well, with the appropriate flags. The second is a language requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [narrowing conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Narrowing_conversions) is (roughly speaking) a conversion between built-in types that might need to truncate or take a modulus on some values because the destination type is not capable of suitably representing a given source value if known at compile time, or some possible source values if the value is not known at compile time.

So conversion from the known value `2` or `4` to a `bool` is a narrowing conversion, since a `bool` can't really represent those numbers, only `0` or `1`.

Ever since C++11, it has been illegal for a program to require a narrowing conversion on any value found within `{` curly braces `}` used for aggregate initialization or list-initialization.

A narrowing conversion is still allowed when the source is not in curly braces, such as your `bool a = 2;`.